# Cannot access mongoose Schema context in Typescript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to apply `.pre`, `.method`, and `.static` functions to my Mongoose Schemas.

I have the following code, but my `this` is either in the wrong context or I'm misunderstanding Schemas.

```
export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    comparePassword(password: string, callback: Function): void;
}

class UserSchema {
    static get schema(): mongoose.Schema {
        let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            email: {
                type: String,
                unique: true,
                lowercase: true
            },
            firstName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            lastName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                type: String,
                select: false
            }
        });

        userSchema.pre('save', this.saveHandler);        
        userSchema.method('comparePassword', this.comparePassword);

        return userSchema;
    }

    static saveHandler(next) {
        let user = this.schema;
        if(!user.isModified('password')) {
              return next();
         }
          bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
              bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                  user.password = hash;
                  next();
              });
          });
    }

    static comparePassword(password: string, callback: Function) {
        let user = this.schema;
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            callback(err, isMatch);
        });
    }
}

export const UserModel = mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema.schema);
```

Typescript is throwing errors that `Property 'isModified' does not exist on type 'Schema'.`

However, in javascript:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    password: { type: String, select: false },
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
});

schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    if(!user.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

does have the correct `this` context. How would I properly structure my Typescript code to have the same effect?

Comment: did you check the definition of the Schema object in the .d.ts? does it have a isModified method defined in it?

Comment: also, where did you get your mongoose typings from?

Comment: It does not have an isModified method. I got them from DT, specifically https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/d4724f8c3e9e11335770556fef3e5ee7265e36c1/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts

Comment: If I make the `.pre` call to be an anonymous function with the function syntax rather than the fat arrow, it works. That's interesting - I would expect the this context to be the same in this instance.

Comment: static methods are not instance dependent. you shouldn't use them if you need instance specific information don't use static methods.

Comment: Whoops. That's not how I meant to use "instance". I mean in terms of this problem.

Comment: well, in this case schema is also a static property.. you should not use this to retrieve static properties though, use the class name instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118159/discussion-between-toskv-and-fedoranimus).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is **this** value inside the static methods. This is your original code.

```
class UserSchema {
    static get schema(): mongoose.Schema {
        let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });
        // this does not refer to UserSchema!
        userSchema.pre('save', this.saveHandler); 
        userSchema.method('comparePassword', this.comparePassword);
        return userSchema;
    }

    static saveHandler(next) {
       ...
    }

    static comparePassword(password: string, callback: Function) {
       ...
    }
}
```

So, a first approach could be changing `this` keyword with `UserSchema` reference

```
class UserSchema {

    static get schema(): mongoose.Schema {
        let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... })
        userSchema.pre('save', UserSchema.saveHandler);        
        userSchema.method('comparePassword', UserSchema.comparePassword);
        return userSchema;
    }

    static saveHandler(next) {
        let user = UserSchema.schema;
        ...
    }

    static comparePassword(password: string, callback: Function) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But, as @toskv said, I would recommend not to use static methods. Typescript is a very big advance from Javascript but do not think as in Java. Use a module-based design.
For example you could define the module **userSchema.ts** as the following template:

```
// private to the module
const _schema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... })
_schema.pre('save', _saveHandler)
_schema.method('comparePassword', _comparePassword)

/** from the outside you'll call it as 
 *
 *  const userSchema = require('...')
 *  userSchema.getSchema()
 */
export function getSchema() {
 return _schema
}

// private to the module
function _saveHandler(next: Function) {
  ...
}

// private to the module
function _comparePassword(next: Function) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function without arrow function works like Fedoranimus said